# drag drop replace - javascript jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

Im looking for a script or code that will allow me to drag a div/img over another one and then replace their positions, for example on a grid, any help appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the JQuery UI library: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
A think this might be a good place to start, depending of how you want to implement it.